# datetime and timespan arithmetic in TSQL via HQL

Tags: t-sql, hql

I need to create an HQL where clause which has the form:

```
where tbl1.DateTimeField + tbl2.TimeSpanField >= :someDateTimeParameter
```

The DateTimeField is of type DateTime

The TimeSpanField is of type BigInt (is this the best option?)

The someDateTimeParameter is a DateTime

writing the HQL query as above translates almost exactly into TSQL, however this is obviously invalid.

1. What do I need to do to get this where clause to work? Is there some HQL trick I can emlpoy?
2. If not, how do I write the HQL to use some TSQL function to do the comparison for me?
3. What TSQL would I need?

Thanks!

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

For 1 and 2 see [Performing Date/Time Math In HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639522/performing-date-time-math-in-hql) for answers.
For 3 use dateadd or datediff (google for t-sql + function name)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up storing the timespans as datetimes offset from 1/1/1900 like this

```
protected readonly DateTime leadTimeAdjustment = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);

[Obsolete("For use by NHibernate only.")]
public virtual DateTime _leadTime { get; protected set; }

public virtual TimeSpan LeadTime
{
    get { return _leadTime - leadTimeAdjustment; }
    set { _leadTime = leadTimeAdjustment.Add(value); }
}
```