# How to perform date operations in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, date, time, hql

I want to perform data time operations using hibernate HQL.

I want to add and subtract two dates as well as I want to subtract 1 year or 1 month from a particular date.

How is this possible using HQL in hibernate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See 
[Performing Date/Time Math In HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639522/performing-date-time-math-in-hql)
for an example.

To use custom sql you must wrote an own hibernate dialect and register:

```
registerFunction("weekday", 
  new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.INTEGER, "to_char(?1,'D')") );
```

Comment: Yes.. I saw that link but in Hibernate there is no provision given for adding or subtracting date properly.

suppose if I want a date before a year using current_timestamp() of HQL. What should be done as there is no additional function given for that.

Is there any better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, on following link I found detailed description of creating custom hibernate dialect for sql server. It is explained in last answer of the link. Hope it will help someone.

https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=995494

Comment: Hi amar4kintu, if my answer has helped, can you please vote or mark the answer with the green checkmark?

Answer (score 10):

You need to create your own dialect. Something like the following:

```
public class MyDialect extends MySQLInnoDBDialect{
      public MyDialect() {
      super();
      registerFunction("date_add_interval", new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.DATE, "date_add(?1, INTERVAL ?2 ?3)"));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Great ... now how You use this in code ... a small sample if possible

Answer (score 5):

This is an open issue in Hibernate.  As of Hibernate 3.3 there is no standard way to handle date comparisons purely in HQL:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2434

Hibernate 4.3 offers functions to access Date/Time in HQL which are:

```
current_timestamp() , current_date() , current_time()
```

Arithmetic operations can be managed by:

```
SECOND(...) , MINUTE(...) , HOUR(...) , DAY(...) , MONTH(...) , YEAR(...)
```

Answer (score 5):

In Hibernate/MySQL (at least)
You can convert to and from a Unix Timestamp.  Since the unix timestamp is an integer you can add an integer number of seconds to it.

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)+ (allowedTimeWindow*86400)) as deadline
```

It has limitations but it's a lot easier than the approaches above.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:  I am a Java novice

I was able to use `current_date() >= fromDate AND dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) <= toDate` in an HQL statement against a Sybase db in Hibernate 3.5.3, without registering any functions.

Answer (score 0):

Usage sample of approach with dialect for JPA + Hibernate 4.3.1 + MySQL 5

public class SampleMySQL5InnoDBDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect {

```
public SampleMySQL5InnoDBDialect() {
    super();
    registerFunction("date_sub_days", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "date_sub(?1, interval ?2 day)"));
}
```

then for your class with mapping annotation:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "SampleEntity.getSampleEntitiesForGapOverlapCalculations", query = "from SampleEntity as se where "
    + "((se.toDate between :startDate and :endDate) or (date_sub_days(se.toDate, se.duration) between :startDate and :endDate)) order by se.toDate asc, se.duration desc")
```

**SampleEntity** has ***toDate*** field of type java.sql.Date and ***duration*** integer field (duration in days) and we are calculating ***fromDate = toDate - duration*** and selecting all entities which have ***fromDate*** or ***toDate*** inside interval ***[startDate, endDate]***.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate4.3 provides native functions to access Dates/Timestamps and to perform arithmatic operations on them

[Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-expressions) is the link to the documentation of what expressions can be used in HQL.
Few of which i am mentioning:
To access date/time:

```
current_date(), current_time(), and current_timestamp()
```

Arithmetic operations can be done by following. These functions take Time as input:

```
second(...), minute(...), hour(...), day(...), month(...), and year(...)
```

One can get absolute difference of in HQL by

```
current_timestamp() - dateInstance
```

where dateInstance can have definition

```
@Column(name = "updated_at")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private java.util.Date updatedAt;
```

The result is in 0.1 seconds. So for a absolute difference of 1 second, the above expression will give result as 10.

So a query would look like :

```
select t from Table t where (current_timestamp() - updatedAt)>600
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres users...

```
registerFunction("dateadd", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "(?1 + INTERVAL ?2)"));
```

with SQL usage like:

```
now() < dateadd(:mydate, '-1 day')
```