# With Hibernate/JPA query inHQL/JQL only how do I set where clause to last x days?

Tags: database, hibernate, date, hql

I am looking for the HQL equivalent of converting x amounts days from current timestamp to a queriable value.

So like this sudo-HQL : 
from Newspaper as newspaper 
where newspaper.published < current_timestamp - days(:daysparam)

And then daysparam is injected as query parameter. And published is date field.

Is this in anyway doable in HQL only, without writing your own hibernate dialect or using criteria in actual code? It seems such as standard feature to not be supported by plain HQL seems strange.

I am using Spring batch's HibernatePagingItemReader which is xml only, so I wanted to avoid the yakshaving of extending that class or creating my own custom dialect etc.

Similar question seems to only suggest calendar critera or new dialect:

[Performing Date/Time Math In HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639522/performing-date-time-math-in-hql)

[How to perform date operations in hibernate HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036657/how-to-perform-date-operations-in-hibernate-hql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something doesn't look quite right: you said that `published` is a `date` field (in the database, I suppose). Then, you are using `current_timestamp` minus an integer value to compare with the date field. As result, you are *not* getting the timestamp for the date in the parameter, you are just getting `current_timestamp - 2`, which I don't believe represents "two days ago" ;-) If you have used `current_date`, I guess it might work.

```
from Newspaper as newspaper where newspaper.published < current_date - :daysparam
```

But still, I'd prefer to leave this calculation to the Java side, so that the query would be:

```
from Newspaper as newspaper where newspaper.published < :start_date
```

This won't work only if you are not using UTC in your servers (which you should).

Comment: True, current_date is more appropiate in this instance, although in theory I could want to get everything less than 4 hours ago.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but I am going to set this as the answer :)