# how to use weekday function in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have MYSQL query

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(CreatedDate), 
    COUNT(CreatedDate), 
    CreatedDate FROM bug_List
GROUP BY 
    WEEKDAY(CreatedDate)
```

But I couldn't find WEEKDAY function in hibernate is there any best way to resolve it

Here i tried from nativeSQL but i got empty array object

query=session.createSQLQuery("SELECT weekday(CreatedDate),
          count(CreatedDate) FROM bug_list GROUP BY WEEKDAY(CreatedDate)");

```
         result=query.list();

        Iterator resultIterator = result.iterator();
        while(resultIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Object[] obj = (Object[]) resultIterator.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(obj[i] + "\t");
                }
            System.out.println("");

        }
```

Comment: Maybe with [native sql](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp%5Fquery)?

Comment: @SérgioMichels please check code snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WEEKDAY` is not standard SQL, and thus if you wish to use Hibernate you must roll a custom `HibernateDialect` in which you do something like the following...

```
registerFunction("weekday",
    new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.INTEGER, "to_char(?1,'D')"));
```

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1037698/591495).

Comment: thnk you very much **veer**. I will try