# How to add minutes to a timestamp column in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have two database columns where one is of type `Timestamp` and the other one is a `Number` holding # of minutes. I have a requirement where I need to add both columns i.e. add minutes to timestamp value and compare it against a parameter which is also a `Timestamp`. The below is my `NamedQuery` that current fails.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. And I would like to implement this using a `Named Query` instead of a `Native` one.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Company.findAllProducts", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p JOIN FETCH p.productDetail pd WHERE (pd.createTimestamp + pd.minutesToActive) > :incomingTimestamp")
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
Parameter value [2015-05-20T14:52:08.764Z] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2015-05-20T14:52:08.764Z] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.validateBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:382) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar!/:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.registerParameterBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:356) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar!/:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.registerParameterBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:347) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar!/:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:373) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar!/:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar!/:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
```

Comment: You probably have to make it a native query because HQL doesn't have (any?) functions for date arithmetic. Which RDBMS are you targeting? Unfortunately, ANSI SQL doesn't really include any standard functions for this purpose either, so the query would be vendor-specific.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036657/how-to-perform-date-operations-in-hibernate-hql

Comment: @MickMnemonic i'm using Oracle. Yes using native query i may be able to achieve that but i really wanted to implement it using a named query.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `NamedQuery` is unable to add a `Timestamp` value with an `Integer`.

Please check if you can change '`Number`' (minute offset field), also to a `Timestamp` field. Else you can do the addition outside of the query.

Could you please give some more details, like is '2015-05-20T14:52:08.764Z' this value coming from pd.createTimestamp? Also, have you tried running this SQL directly in the DB, did it worked?

Comment: that value is coming as a parameter for incomingTimestamp. it fails before it can create SQL (so don't have SQL yet) unless you meant if i've written a native query which i haven't.

Comment: I believe the issue is with the SQL itself (specifically this part, (pd.createTimestamp + pd.minutesToActive) ). Could you please try to run the native SQL in the DB and check if it woks. I am assuming here that, if the NamedQuery has to work, the same query has to work natively, except for the query parameters.
You can try running this .. 
SELECT p FROM Product p JOIN FETCH p.productDetail pd WHERE (pd.createTimestamp + pd.minutesToActive) > '2015-05-20T14:52:08.764Z'