# Common functions for oracle and mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate

In below query I wanted to group by just on date not time that's why I used `TO_DATE` function

```
select TO_DATE(e.created_dt, 'dd-mm-yy'),sum(CURRENT_BAL) from sbill.act_resource_t e group by TO_DATE(e.created_dt, 'dd-mm-yy');
```

so as of now its working fine with oracle but as per our business requirements application should support both `oracle` and `mysql` without write two different queries;

so do we have any solution for that which should works with both `oracle` and `mysql` ?

Note :- I am using `hql`

Below code :

```
  Query query1 = entityManager.createQuery("select TO_DATE(e.createdDt, 'dd-mm-yy'),sum(CURRENT_BAL) from ActT e group by TO_DATE(e.createdDt, 'dd-mm-yy')");

    List<Object> result=query1.getResultList();
```

Comment: Nope date functions are very different.

Comment: @P.Salmon   this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036657/how-to-perform-date-operations-in-hibernate   ,  related to custom dialect ... i am little bit confused , this solution will work for me ?

Comment: The link refers to HQL but your question title is refers to oracle and mysql. What are you actually using.

Comment: yes i am using hql ,  i am editing my question

Comment: Edited questions... sorry for inconvenience..

Comment: I know nothing of hql but the mysql function is str_to_date.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Does `CAST(createdDt AS DATE)` work?

Comment: And this is not how you solve the problem of supporting multiple databases. Search for ORM.

Comment: @SalmanA   earlier i tried with that , but  records are not coming proper seems its considering time as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the functions differ between the databases, we need a [dynamic query](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/Dynamic-Queries). But we can do it efficiently by creating a custom conversion method, which will select the right implementation based on the current database type. And the query itself will remain common (The solution uses [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA) library):

```java
public static final FormatModel DD_MM_YY = Format.dateModel(Format.DD, Format.MM, Format.YY);
public static boolean isOracle() {
    return false; //should return the actual value in runtime
}

@Local
// picks the right implementation
public static Function1<String, Date> AS_DATE() {
    if (isOracle())
        return s -> TO_DATE(s, DD_MM_YY); //oracle

    return s -> STR_TO_DATE(s, "%d-%m-%y"); // mysql
}
```

Now we can write a generic implementation:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "act_resource_t", schema = "sbill")
@Data
public static class ActResource {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private int currentBAL;
    private String createdDT;
}

// for the result
@Tuple
@Data
public static class BalanceByDate {
    private Date date;
    private int balance;
}

...

public BalanceByDate balanceByDate() {
    FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((ActResource e) -> {

        // with lambda we inject the right implementation
        Date createdDate = alias(AS_DATE().apply(e.getCreatedDT()), BalanceByDate::getDate);
        Integer balance = alias(SUM(e.getCurrentBAL()), BalanceByDate::getBalance);

        SELECT(createdDate, balance);
        FROM(e);
        GROUP(BY(createdDate));
    });

    return query.createQuery(em, BalanceByDate.class).getSingleResult();
}
```

This is the resulting SQL for MySQL:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(t0.created_dt, '%d-%m-%y') AS date, SUM(t0.current_bal) AS balance 
FROM sbill.act_resource_t t0 
GROUP BY  STR_TO_DATE(t0.created_dt, '%d-%m-%y')
```