# Get records for last 3 days via Spring JPA Repository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity which contains field `date`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="messages", schema = "users")
...
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "author")
    private String author;

    @Column(name = "tags")
    private String tags;

    @Column(name = "message_date")
    private LocalDate date;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       ...    
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {

    Message findByMessageId(Long id);

}
```

I'm using Spring Data JPA with repository. I want to get all messages from database for last 3 days (field `date`). How can I do it with Spring JPA?

```
@Query(...?)
List<Message> findBy...?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform date operations in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036657/how-to-perform-date-operations-in-hibernate)

Comment: Unfortunately, nope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to split the logic from the actual queries. A service could handle all the intermediate things, e.g.:

```
@Service
public class MessageService {
    private final MessageRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public MessageService(MessageRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    List<Message> getLastThreeDays() {
        // subtract 3 days from today
        LocalDate threeDaysAgoDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(3);
        return this.repository.findAllWithDateAfter(threeDaysAgoDate);

    }
}
```

and your repository stays nice and clean:

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {

    Optional<Message> findByMessageId(Long id);

    @Query("select m from Message m where date >= :threeDaysAgoDate")
    List<Message> findAllWithDateAfter(@Param("threeDaysAgoDate") LocalDate threeDaysAgoDate);

}
```