# how to use date() in hibernate criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I would like to use Date() function in hibernate criteria, since one field is timestamp.

My sql would be:

```
"select * from feed where DATE(date) = DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 5 DAY"
```

When I try in criteria:

```
critera.add(Restrictions.eq("DATE(date)", "DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 5 DAY"));
```

I get:

```
could not resolve property: DATE(date) of: com.mycomapany.model.Feed
```

I have there in feed a field by the name date.

What is the problem? I am using MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is to use the criteria api which you started to use.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(LOCALIZATION);
//Add 5 Days
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);
criteria.add(Expression.ge("dateColumn",c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably find a way to make this work, but in my opinion, this is the wrong way to approach it.

One of the major features of Hibernate is the abstraction of the database-vendor-specific features, via the Hibernate Dialect.

You are attempting to access MySQL features directly, but through the vendor-neutral interface, thus your difficulty. Hibernate could have support for date intervals , but does not - see https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2434

So, the options seem to be:

- Calculate the date ranges in your code, rather than in the HQL
- Do what you need to do in SQL rather than HQL
- Create a custom Hibernate Dialect, as in [Performing Date/Time Math In HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639522/performing-date-time-math-in-hql)

Answer (score 1):

Using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

```java
public List<Feed> findByDaysFromToday(int daysFromToday) {
    return em.createQuery(
            "SELECT f FROM Feed f WHERE f.date BETWEEN :start AND :end")
            .setParameter("start",
                          new LocalDate()
                                  .toDateMidnight()
                                  .toDate(),
                          TemporalType.DATE)
            .setParameter("end",
                          new LocalDate().plusDays(daysFromToday)
                                  .toDateMidnight()
                                  .toDateTime()
                                  .minusMillis(1)
                                  .toDateTime()
                                  .toDate(),
                          TemporalType.DATE)
            .getResultList();
}
```