# Interval in Hibernate syntax

Tags: hibernate, hql

I would like to query the next sentence in Hibernate:

```
from Attribute where tDate between ((select max(tDate) from Attribute)-interval '5 minutes') and (select max(tDate) from Attribute)
```

However, HQL does not understand interval. How could I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639522/performing-date-time-math-in-hql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate does not have interval keyword.

You can rewrite query to use [between](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3204) keyword or you can use native query