# specify named parameter in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a query like

```
"select a from tableName a where a.column1 = : parameter1 and a.column2 < (systimestamp - interval '5' minute)
```

I want pass this constant value 5 as parameter. Kindly suggest me how can I do that ?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `interval :parameter2 minute` instead of `interval '5' minute` ?

Comment: No.... its not working.. i have tried it already..

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot.. Finally I got that "interval" keyword does not work in hibernate. If any time related operation is required then we should do it in java.
See below answer

[Performing Date/Time Math In HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639522/performing-date-time-math-in-hql)