# spring data query select pageable entries within past week

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring data and am trying to write a query which returns all entries within the past week. The following is my repository code:

```
@Query("select l from LogEvent l where (l.entryTimestamp < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND l.entryTimestamp IN l")
Page<LogEvent> findAllRecent(Pageable pageable);
```

I want to select all LogEvent objects which have a "entryTimestamp" variable holding the time at which they were created. I want to grab all entries created within the last 7 days. One of the issues I'm having is how to get a TIMESTAMP - 7 days that I can compare to each entity's timestamp. I've tried a number of things in looking around, like "interval '7' days" and some other examples I could find.

It's obviously lacking that week old timestamp comparison, but right now I feel like it should run and return all the LogEvent objects. As it is now, I get the following error: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER. Any pointers/help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: if you use hibernate, this may be a viable option http://stackoverflow.com/a/641421/775513

Comment: why don't you introduce the `@Query("select l from LogEvent l where (l.entryTimestamp >= :start)") Page<LogEvent> findAllRecent(@Param("start") LocalDateTime start, Pageable pageable)` method, which will be called with `LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(7)` parameter, in case required you can change the interval in days.

Comment: @IlyaDyoshin Hmm. So at the datebase level as well as the java bean level, the entry timestamp value is of type TIMESTAMP & Timestamp. Is it possible to make LocalDateTime work with the timestamp types?

Comment: @Caleb than you can run something like `Timestamp.from(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(7).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));`   or redefine your mapping to  have `entryTimestamp` being mapped to `LocalDateTime`

Comment: So I would pass that in in the java implementation file? E.g:  `@Override
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
 public Page<LogEvent> findAllRecent(Timestamp timeStamp,Pageable page) {
  return logEventRepository.findAllRecent(Timestamp.from(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(7).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)), page.previousOrFirst());
 }` Sorry, this is ugly formatting

Comment: And in the repository: `@Query("select l from LogEvent l where (l.entryTimestamp >= :start)")
 Page<LogEvent> findAllRecent(@Param("start") LocalDateTime start, Pageable pageable);`

Comment: Or I could keep as timestamp object and do this: `timeStamp.setTime(timeStamp.getTime()-604800000);`

Comment: you can create repository method  with LocalDateTime or Timestamp parameter - as you like.  All the implementation is made by SpringData - you don't need to implement it at all. And introduce service to fetch "last week" entries.   where you call your DAO method

Comment: Hi, how to get within 30 days records? can any one help me?